# Declare a variable in Link so Controller loads separate layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link that calls this:

```
<%=link_to 'Free Trial', '/sign_up', :rel => "#signup", :class => "sign_up_button"%>
```

Which renders mysite.com/sign_up - This loads a partial in a Jquery light box. However What I would love to do is have a controller statement where if the link above is clicked it renders the page with no layout. But if the user navigates to mysite.com/sign_up from the address bar, they see the same page but with a layout.

I am thinking in my controller something like this:

```
 def sign_up
   if :variable == true
   render :layout => false
   else
   render :layout => 'layouts/sign_up'
   end  
 end
```

then in my link declaring a variable it can pass to the controller? something like

```
:variable => 'true'
```

I am thinking about this in the right way? How would the above work?

The main reason for this is so that if mysite.com/login is loaded on its own (without Jquery) then it will still look good!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways :

- You can do as you are thinking, and set your `partial` flag via POST. Replace `/signup` with `/signup?partial=1` and in your controller `if params[:partial]`
- Or you can render conditionnaly looking at `request.xhr?` (but ajax headers must be setted correctly by your js framework)

Comment: I went with the partial=1 params in the end as it seemed simple and replicable in the controller - thanks